# How to show another selectbox when you choose from another selectbox in Django

Tags: django

I am new to Django. 
Now I have class defined below

```
PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICE = [['1', 'Fixed (TODO)'],
                    ['2', 'Trajectory (TODO)'],
                    ['3', 'Error_Detecting'],
                    ['4', 'Error_Correcting']]
FIXED_TYPE_CHOICE = [['1', 'Prefix',
                      '2', 'Suffix']]

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    # title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    automata_file  = forms.FileField(required = True)
    transducer_file = forms.FileField(required = True)
    property_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICE,
                                      required=True)
    fixed_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FIXED_TYPE_CHOICE,
                                   required=True)
    debug_output = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

I have this PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICE showed in the front html

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.property_type.errors }}
    <label for="id_a">Select <u>a type</u> of property:</label>
    {{ form.property_type }}
</div>
```

and I want to show the FIXED_TYPE_CHOICE if I choose the first choice "Fixed (TODO)" in the PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICE.
I read the docs about Django, and I think it may be implemented in this way:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.property_type.errors }}
    <label for="id_a">Select <u>a type</u> of property:</label>
    {{ form.property_type }}
</div>
{% if form.property_type=='1' %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.fixed_type.errors }}
        <label for="id_a">Select <u>a fixed type</u> of property:</label>
    {   { form.fixed_type }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

But I can't do that.
What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form.property_type` is a BoundForm object, if you want to access its value you'll need to use `form.property_type.value`

Which is why your comparison of `{% if form.property_type=='1'}` doesn't work.

For more details see [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs) about 2/3rds of the way down, under the Customizing the Form Template section.

For updating without a page refresh, you'll need Javascript like the following (make sure you also include the jQuery library (http://jquery.com/):

```
$("#property_type").change (function() {
    if($(this).val() == '1') {
        $("#fixed_type").show();
    } else {
        $("#fixed_type").hide();
    }
} )
```

And make sure that the give the dropdowns corresponding id attributes (`id="property_type"`) for example.

Comment: Are you trying to get it to show the second box as soon as you select "Fixed" from the dropdown, or after a page refresh? If you want it to show up without a page refresh, you'll need to use Javascript.

Comment: I am trying to show the second box as soon as possible without a page refresh. And do you know the code of Javascript?

Comment: Updated my answer with some Javascript, that should give you a place to start

Comment: Mind "accepting" my answer if that worked for you? You can accept by pressing the checkmark next to it.